# jQuery posts data to wrong relative URL

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-post

I have an ASP.Net MVC application. I am trying to post data to an action, and then just render the output. I have a page where you can view a product, so www.mysite.com/product/details/1 shows the product. On this page, I render a partial view through RenderAction() that contains some pricing logic. I want the user to select some options and then have jquery post the options to get the new price.

However, when I call

```
$.post({
  url : "price/getprice",
  data : {"options" : chosenOptions},
  success : function(data) {
              $("#price").text(data);
            }
});
```

The url is posting to `www.mysite.com/product/details/price/getprice` which doesn't exist. I've tried posting to "~/price/getprice/" but it does the same thing. Why won't it go to my PriceController's GetPrice(FormCollection form) action??

This should post to `www.mysite.com/price/getprice`. When I look in the Net tab in firebug, it says it's posting this:

```
http://localhost:42427/Product/Details/%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

If I look at the response in Firebug, the application is throwing an exception:

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Details(Int32)' in
>   'PrintPlaceWebsite.Controllers.ProductController'.

But I'm not trying to post to that location so...ugh.

Comment: What URL *should* it POST to?

Comment: Can you just change the url to be the full path:

/price/getprice

Isn't price the controller and not product?

Comment: @Nick This should post to `www.mysite.com/price/getprice`. 
@Spinon I've tried ~/price/getprice, /price/getprice, and the full path www.mysite.com/price/getprice.

Comment: How do you get your current URL? Are you using [Url.Action()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you specified a relative URL, so if this code is on site `www.mysite.com/a/b/c`, the URL will point to `/a/b/price/getprice`.

You probably want to specify an absolute URL:

```
$.post({
  url : "/price/getprice",
  //     ^-- leading slash
  data : {"options" : chosenOptions},
  success : function(data) {
              $("#price").text(data);
            }
});
```

Comment: +1 - Your example needs a tweak though, it would be pointing to `a/b/price/getprice`, since the `c` has no trailing slash :)

Comment: @scottm: If you do that, what says Firebug? If you have a routing issue, than it is a server problem.

Comment: @scottm - It shouldn't be related to routing if you're seeing the URL in your question in Firebug/Chrome console.  It may be a caching issue with your script files?  There's no way that `url` in the `$.post()` call should go to the URL you're seeing.

Comment: @Felix, the last little bit is the result in firebug when using this path (/price/getprice)

Comment: @Nick, that's why I'm pulling my hair out :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as JQuery knows it is basing its AJAX calls on the current location which, im guessing, is www.mysite.com/product/details/. Just as if you had a link to "myPage.html" would try to go to www.mysite.com/product/details/myPage.html.

I would suggest you resolve the URL in your View with something like..

```
<% = ResolveUrl("~/price/getprice") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the URL router is mixing things up. Just replace the path with an absolute (full) one.

```
$.post({
  url : "http://mywesbite.com/price/getprice",
  data : {"options" : chosenOptions},
  success : function(data) {
          $("#price").text(data);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out it was a little typo on my part (an everyone else's because you all copied it).

To reiterate:

```
$.post({
  url : "/price/getprice",
  data : {"options" : chosenOptions},  <<<<< Right here. dang.
  success : function(data) {
          $("#price").text(data);
        }
});
```

Do you see it?

```
$.post({
  url : "/price/getprice",
  data : { options : chosenOptions},  <<<<< no quotes. arg.
  success : function(data) {
          $("#price").text(data);
        }
});
```

Comment: This might be the solution but it is not *bulletproof*. You can have issues with it just when switching between IIS and Visual Studio webserver or when using virtual directory in IIS and when not using one. You need to use Url.Action() like this $("#Url").autocomplete('<%=Url.Action("getprice", "price", new { options = "..."}) %>', {...});

Answer (score 0):

The one which worked for me is:

In the view : add

```
<span data-url="@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")" id="getValues" class="hidden"></span>
```

Note: Make sure to use the forward slash('/')

In the Jquery file,

```
var getValues = $('span#getValues').attr('data-url');
```

In the Ajax call, Set

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: getValues,
            data: { id: abc},
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
             }
       });
```